# Why do I get an error within matlab(octave) using the vpi package using rdivide, mrdivide or quotient?

Tags: matlab, package, octave, matlab-guide, matlab-deployment

I am using octave for private use(I'm a student and there is unfortunately no free version of Matlab for students at my university)
Now I try to implement an algorithm using big numbers; So I started downloading the vpi package here:

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22725-variable-precision-integer-arithmetic

Now I put the data in the right place and started working with it which was really great;

So I started for example with:

```
 a=vpi(12989487973402)
 a =

     12989487973402
```

and then

```
 a=a^10
 a = 1367477916402329222848766554412698316550418920659968300260110320792
 46979577273468682364762841107165766713454228653820366806955009024
```

which works really awesome; However I try now to use one of the commands rdivide, mrdivide or quotient of this package which is actually made for vpi numbers and should actually work; However it doesn't work with bigger numbers:

E.g.

```
  b=vpi(129892);
  c=b^2

  c = 
    2191528947700288

 rdivide(c,2)
 ans =

     1095764473850144
```

However when the numbers only a little bigger, I suddenly get error messages (with functions rdivide, mrdivide and quotient exactly the same ones)

```
 c=b^4

   c = 
    284662078074685808896

 rdivide(c,2)
 error: 'iszero' undefined near line 49 column 6
 error: called from:
 error:   /home/john/test/@vpi/times.m at line 55, column 3
 error:   /home/john/test/@vpi/mtimes.m at line 27, column 7
 error: evaluating argument list element number 1
 error:   /home/john/test/@vpi/quotient.m at line 103, column 9
 >>>error:   /home/john/test/@vpi/rdivide.m at line 43, column 5
```

Now I'm wondering if it is a problem of Octave and I need to have the original matlab or if it is a bug in the program or if I'm too stupid to use it???

Can someone help??? Thank you

EDIT: rdivide, mrdivide and quotient are working all very similar and they are supposed to return a./b for rdive/mrdivide/quotient(a,b) if a is divisible by b

Comment: I can not confirm your problem with octave 4.0.0. It seems you only added the subfolder `@vpi` instead of the full folder to your search path.

Comment: So you don't have it with your version? :) So maybe I need to look for another version...

Comment: Daniel - are you still there? I just managed to download the latest version but I still get the same error message? Do you have any idea what is wrong? :(

Comment: Found the solution; One file was corrupted somehow... Thank you :)